# How to host same code for multiple products?

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have three products like google have drive, gmail, docs. Now for all three I have a same database. All three have different code but user-management code is same for all. Example user role , privilege management.
So what is the way to integrate same code in all the application? So I need not to re-write it for all products.

I'm using Node.js/express, Docker, Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your shared code to volume or any path on node, then mount it to your applications/containers.

More information about [Volumes in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

If you need further assistance, please provide more information about your deployment.